# Use deeplink with google play link to open app if app is install, otherwise open store

Tags: android, google-play, deeplink

Let's imagine I have a link of my app on the store like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id

Say I want to open my app if it's installed, or let the store handle the link if my app isn't installed.

Say I put the `intent-filter` like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="play.google.com"
                android:path="/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Happy case would be:

- My app is installed. The link matches the path. Then open the app
- My app not install. The only handler is the store, so the store is opened

But. As I know, the query part of the link (the part since "?") won't work. So the code above cannot be resolved to my app. Therefore, the store handles that link.

If I changed to `android:path="/store/apps/details`, it still won't work because it feels like the store handles all play.google.com link

Is there anyway I can make it work?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

check this doc. it will be work.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: This could be a solution, I'll check it out. Thank you.